# ZX axis 2 dof orientation interpolation

Tags: interpolation, orientation, kinematics

I have 2 DOF orientation for Z and X axes how can I interpolate between 2 orientations? I have interpolated for 3 DOF orientation with slerp using quaternions and rotation matrix for inverse kinematics, but I could not deal with 2 DOF orientaion one.

Comment: Why can't you just use the slerp formula with your 2D vectors? E.g., the generic formula found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp

Comment: I will look at but If I know true about slerp , it follows shortest or longest path according to dot product of 2 quaternion vectors. Thus, I think slerp needs one more dof for implementing it.